# \ifthenelse within \caption, \listoftables does not work

Tags: captions, conditionals

EXAMPLE 1 below works fine but EXAMPLE 2 produces "undefined control sequence". The only difference is the `\vlabel` command within brackets in the `\caption` command. What is the problem?

EXAMPLE 1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\vlabel}[1]
{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{numbersa}}{Numbers A}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}
\caption[Numbers A]{\vlabel{numbersa}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

EXAMPLE 2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\vlabel}[1]
{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{numbersa}}{Numbers A}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}
\caption[\vlabel{numbersa}]{\vlabel{numbersa}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, Code highlighting and markup works just like over at TeXwelt.de.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expansion of [`ifthen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) macros causes problems in the auxiliary files. You either need to `\protect` them

```
...
\caption[\protect\vlabel{numbersa}]{\vlabel{numbersa}}
...
```

or use an alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\vlabel}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{numbersa}=0
    Numbers A%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\listoftables% LoF

\begin{table} \caption[Numbers A]{\vlabel{numbersa}} \end{table}

\begin{table} \caption[\vlabel{numbersa}]{\vlabel{numbersa}} \end{table}

\end{document}
```

`\pdfstrcmp` (requires e-TeX) is expandable, making sure that only `Numbers A` makes its way into the LoF.

Comment: Excellent, both solutions work perfectly, thank you very much!